# tcsh array variable substitution

Tags: arrays, variables, tcsh

I'm attempting to modify a script that works for a different application.  i could start over, but I'd like to learn how to do this.  Here are some arrays I'm manually setting instead of using user input or an input file:

```
set mbeg= (1 2 3 4)
set mmid= (5 6 7 8)
set mend= (9 0 0 0)
```

what I really want to do is loop through `$time` and `$case` and have it return the array value for the loop variables.

```
foreach time (beg mid end)
   foreach case (1 2 3 4)
      echo \${m$time}[$case]
```

For this example, I want it to return:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0

I can get as far as getting `echo \${m$time}` to return "mbeg" but i can't figure out how to get the array counter in there.  Is this something simple that can be done, or should I change the strategy?  Other strategies include brute force input of the array name and if/else statements to choose only the array corresponding to the `$time` variable.

```
foreach time (beg mid end)
foreach j ( 1 2 3 4 )
   if ($time == beg) then
      echo $mbeg[$j]
   elseif ( $time == mid ) then
      echo $mmid[$j]
   else
      echo $mend[$j]
```

I could also attempt to read from an input file.  To date, I have done this using grep and sed to reduce the file to a single variable.
Thanks.